# exporting graphics has missing features in pdf format in 11.0.1

Tags: graphics, export

I am creating graphics with the following code

```
pts={{-0.680422, 0.0957483}, {-1.07217, 0.283248}, {-0.0721688, 
0.283248}, {0.536084, 0.470748}, {0.927831, 0.283248}, {-0.463916, 
0.470748}, {0.319578, 0.0957483}, {-0.680422, 1.72874}, {-1.07217, 
1.91624}, {-0.0721688, 1.91624}, {0.536084, 2.10374}, {0.927831, 
1.91624}, {-0.463916, 2.10374}, {0.319578, 1.72874}};
fig=Graphics[{GraphicsComplex[pts,Line[{{6, 4, 5, 7, 1, 2, 6}, {13, 11, 12, 14, 8, 9, 13}, {3, 6}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 7}, {3, 1}, {3, 
  2}, {3, 6}, {10, 13}, {10, 11}, {10, 12}, {10, 14}, {10, 
  8}, {10, 9}, {10, 13}, {6, 13}, {4, 11}, {5, 12}, {7, 14}, {1, 
  8}, {2, 9}, {6, 13}}]]}];
```

The figure is exported into different formats using

```
Export["fig.jpeg", fig, ImageResolution -> 600]
Export["fig.png", fig, ImageResolution -> 600]
Export["fig.pdf", fig, ImageResolution -> 600]
```

The files exported are of 224kB, 106kB and 2kB respectively. Of all these, pdf file has the lowest size and highest resolutions and very sharp image even at 2400%. But the image in pdf file looks like

[image: image from pdf file having missing feature]

The missing feature in the pdf file is the horizontal line connecting the extreme vertices on both the faces.

I tried using `Rasterize` option while exporting. This is increasing the file size and restricting the image resolution.

Is there any other optimized solution for this.

Thank you.

Comment: I do not see this problem in version 11.3.0. EDIT: In fact I do not even see it in version 11.0.1 on macOS.  Try fully restarting Mathematica and dropping the ImageResolution option. If the problem persists, it may be a platform-specific bug. Please mention your OS.

Comment: I am using windows 10. Restarting Mathematica and dropping image resolution in "export" options also could not help!